# How to check if a file exists in the 's3' / 'azure' path using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to check if a file exists in the 's3' / 'azure' path using node js. `fs.stat()` or `fs.existsSync(path)` returns false  even if the file exists in the path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if object exists AWS S3 Node.JS sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26726862/how-to-determine-if-object-exists-aws-s3-node-js-sdk)

Comment: The solution is, where '**request**' is [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request),  
    
<!-- language: lang-js --> const req = require('request');
       req
        .get('azure_image_path')
        .on('response', function (res) {
          if (res.statusCode === 200) {
            //On Sucsess do something
          } else {
            //On Error, handle the error
          }
        })`
With all other methods it fails, with this method the success and failures results are returned. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/request

```js
const request = require('request'); 
request
        .get(cdn_image_path)
        .on('response', function (res) {
          if (res.statusCode === 200) {
            //Do something
          } else {
            //Do something if file is absent
          }
```

By this way you can check the presence of the file in the CDN path. Provided the authentication credentials are updated in the server.